# bazel build Tensorflow from source

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

I have many big deep learning tasks in python 3.6 ahead and wanted to build tensorflow (CPU only) from source, as my MacBook Pro with Touchbar 13" noted that tensorflow would run faster if it were build with SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 and FMA support. There are quite a lot questions on StackOverflow and GitHub regarding that topic and I read them all. None of which is addressing why it is not working for me.

I strictly followed the instructions provided by https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources

my configure looks like this

```
./configure
Please specify the location of python. [Default is /anaconda/bin/python]: /anaconda/python.app/Contents/MacOS/python
Please specify optimization flags to use during compilation when bazel option "--config=opt" is specified [Default is -march=native]: 
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with Google Cloud Platform support? [y/N] n
No Google Cloud Platform support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with Hadoop File System support? [y/N] n
No Hadoop File System support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with the XLA just-in-time compiler (experimental)? [y/N] n
No XLA JIT support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with VERBS support? [y/N] n
No VERBS support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Found possible Python library paths:
  /anaconda/python.app/Contents/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Please input the desired Python library path to use.  Default is [/anaconda/python.app/Contents/lib/python3.6/site-packages]

Using python library path: /anaconda/python.app/Contents/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with OpenCL support? [y/N] n
No OpenCL support will be enabled for TensorFlow
Do you wish to build TensorFlow with CUDA support? [y/N] n
No CUDA support will be enabled for TensorFlow
INFO: Starting clean (this may take a while). Consider using --async if the clean takes more than several minutes.
Configuration finished
```

with bazel 0.4.5 I then try to do the build as in the instructions

```
bazel build --config=opt //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

This is executed without error but it gives literally hundreds of warnings. I can provide such as an example, but there hardly any snippets that go on without warning.

I appreciate ever help, thank you all very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately compiler warnings are a fact of life. However, many of these come from external libraries which are pulled into the build. These can be filtered out with the "output_filter" argument to Bazel:

```
bazel build --config=opt --output_filter='^//tensorflow' //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package
```

This limits output to warnings generated by TensorFlow code (you can also turn warnings off entirely this way, but that takes all the fun out of compiling). Since the tooling used to build matches what TensorFlow is developed with more closely, there are fewer warnings (I get some about multi-line comment continuations, a bunch of signed/unsigned integer comparisons, and some about variables which "may" be uninitialized).

None of these indicate definite bugs, just patterns of code which are sometimes bug-prone. If the compiler knew something was wrong, it would emit an error instead. Which is a long way of saying there's nothing to worry about.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I (successfully) built und installed tensorflow (got some 40 warnings though), unfortunately it is as slow as it was before using SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 and FMA support. Thanks anyways, your answer helped in the process!

Comment: Interesting. The speedup from SIMD does depend on the ops used. The biggest speedup I'm aware of is matrix multiply on the CPU (can be quite significant). Many models are IO bound, however.